# How to provoke a timer trigger in glassfish?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, timer

We need some consistency in our functional test cases.
The best we can do currently is to wait for an estimated time before the Java EE timers in the product should have been triggered. It would be much more predictable if the test cases could trigger the timers programmatically, probably with JMX.

How can this be done? Is there a JMX interface to the Glassfish Timer facility which we can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its apparently impossible, since the question remain unanswered for almost three months.

However, I realized that for testing purposes it is enough to be notified when the triggering has actually occured. (Triggering it actively will only buy me time at the trade for quality)

I'm adding monitoring for event completions instead, but thanks for letting me know that it's actually impossible;)